# How to run desktop Word AddIn with Angular 11.0.5 in MS office 2016

Tags: angular, office-js, office-addins

I'm Try to load my add-ins in office but not working. it's work fine in online platform. I'll try With Angular 5.2.11 and MS Word 2016 my AddIn working fine when upgrading the version of angular to 11.0.5 after that Add-in does not load. below is my environment detail and code link can any one help me.

**[Here is my code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sftv5yFuH7yzyQHC34oH52wxopHR8KgP/view?usp=sharing)**

**Additional Details :**

- AddIn working fine with Word online version
- Add-in does not load with MS Word 2016/2019/365 desktop version after upgrading to latest angular version.

**Environment detail :**

- PC Desktop : Windows 10
- Browser on Web - Microsoft Edge, Mozila Firefox
- Office version - 2016/2019, office 365
- 64 bit Operating System

**Image for after running project**
[Desktop addin image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYeab.png)

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. What exactly goes wrong, when? Explain the wrong behaviour and/or quote all errors in full. Also, linking to external code is discouraged.

Comment: Added more details in the description. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You might try to disable Ivy compilation. in tsconfig.json add

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
```

Comment: tried above solution but not working. Any other suggestions?